# haskell read a file and convert it map of list

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary, char

input file is txt :

000011S\n

0001110\n

001G111\n

0001000\n

Result is:

[["0","0","0","0","1","1","S"], ["0","0","0","1","1","1","0"] [...]]

Read a text file with

```
file <- openFile nameFile ReadMode
```

and the final output
    [["a","1","0","b"],["d","o","t","2"]]
is a map with list of char

try to:

```
convert x = map (map read . words) $ lines x
```

but return [[string ]]

As it could do to return the output I want? [[Char]], 
is there any equivalent for word but for char?

Comment: I have trouble understanding the question - but you know that `String` is just `[Char]`?

Comment: can you please post the file content and what your expected answer should be?

Comment: Yes String is just [Char] but 
but I get make double list, where each line of text is a list that is part of another list

Comment: you get the wrapped `String`s because you did the double `map` there - can you please edit your question and provide the input and the expected output? I really have trouble if your input is supposed to be `"a10b\ndot2"` or if this is the expected outupt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### one solution

```
convert :: String -> [[String]]
convert = map (map return) . lines
```

should do the trick

#### remark

the `return` here is a neat trick to write `\c -> [c]` - wrapping a `Char` into a singleton list as lists are a monad

#### how it works

Let me try to explain this:

- `lines` will split the input into lines: `[String]` which each element in this list being one line
- the outer `map (...) . lines` will then apply the function in `(...)` to each of this lines
- the function inside: `map return` will again map each character of a line (remember: a `String` is just a list of `Char`) and will so apply `return` to each of this characters
- now `return` here will just take a character and put it into a singleton list: `'a' -> [a] = "a"` which is exactly what you wanted

#### your example

```
Prelude> convert "000011S\n0001110\n001G111\n0001000\n"
[["0","0","0","0","1","1","S"]
,["0","0","0","1","1","1","0"]
,["0","0","1","G","1","1","1"]
,["0","0","0","1","0","0","0"]]
```

---

#### concerning your comment

if you expect `convert :: String -> [[Char]]` (which is just `String -> [String]` then all you need is `convert = lines`!

Comment: Thanks , but one question because the output is [[String] ] instead of [[Char]]? do not understand, does not create problems of type?

Comment: if it works , but do not quite understand , I need to practice more . Thank you

Comment: I added a comment to your question - but note that your example was using `[[String]]` ;)

Comment: if you tell me where you have trouble in understanding I will try to help you ^^

Comment: I agree now I understand better! Thanks so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

`[[Char]] == [String]`

```
Prelude> map (map head) [["a","1","0","b"],["d","o","t","2"]]
["a10b","dot2"]
```

will fail for empty Strings though.

or `map concat [[...]]`